# Create Multiple Lightboxs for Multiple Elements on Single Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am curious on how one would have multiple lightbox instances on a single page with different content, without having to duplicate the jQuery code for each instance?

The example is as follows:

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('a').click(function(){
      jQuery('.lightbox').fadeIn('1000');
      return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="unique-lightbox-1" class="lightbox">
<p>Unique content for unique lightbox 1.</p>
</div>
<div id="unique-lightbox-2" class="lightbox">
<p>Unique content for unique lightbox 2.</p>
</div>
<div id="unique-lightbox-3" class="lightbox">
<p>Unique content for unique lightbox 3.</p>
</div>
```

How could I re-factor the code above to be unique for each element that has the lightbox class?

Comment: can you please be a little more specific about your HTML structure?

Comment: @Spokey: Added HTML structure example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example specify which `lightbox id` the `a` should have by storing it in `data`

```
<a href='#' data-light='1'>Lightbox 1</a>
<a href='#' data-light='2'>Lightbox 2</a>
<a href='#' data-light='3'>Lightbox 3</a>
```

The you get `data` in your `script`

```
jQuery('a').click(function(){
   jQuery('#unique-lightbox-' + $(this).data('light')).fadeIn('1000');
   return false;
});
```

Or if you have all your `a` in one parent. You could use their `index`

```
jQuery('a').click(function(){
   jQuery('.lightbox:eq('+($(this).index()+1)+')').fadeIn('1000');
   return false;
});
```